# Prevent the default blue selection on click

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

As a normal website, when I develop website as a native android application,
There is a blue rectangle selection on the area I clicked after the click like a normal site while surfing in the android.

I would like to know if there is any way preventing that, so the applicatin will have a real native-like GUI.

Thanks!

Comment: What about using CSS property outline: none;

Comment: ...on the :selection pseudo selector

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following CSS:

```
a {
   outline: 0;
}
```

For what it's worth, that border is there for accessibility, so if that is important to you, you may wish to consider keeping it.

Comment: +1 for the point on accessibility. Especially with small links, it's important that the user knows they've successfully clicked the correct link. This isn't such an issue in antive apps as the response is usually immediate whereas browser pages require a second or two, especially on slow connections