# Remove blue highlight over html image when clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I am making a custom Application in Android. I am displaying a html page with an img tag inside a div.

```
<div class="press">
    <img src="but.png" width="150" height="62" border="0"/>
</div>
```

In the javascript I am writing:

```
$(".press").bind("click",function()    
{
//display something
});
```

When I click on the image, the click is working but the image is surrounded with a blue overlay.

[Image 1](http://amazeinfotainment.com/example/IMG_1313.JPG)

[Image 2 when image clicked](http://amazeinfotainment.com/example/IMG_1315.JPG)

I dont understand how to remove it. I have tried many ways but none of the answers work. Please help. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent the default blue selection on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433062/prevent-the-default-blue-selection-on-click)

Comment: hey ryan ... the solution in that post did not work for me...

Answer (score 33):

You can prevent selection on your page through css. You can change the * selector to the element selector you want to prevent from selection.

```
/*IE9*/
*::selection 
{
    background-color:transparent;
} 
*::-moz-selection
{
    background-color:transparent;
}
*
{        
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    /*IE10*/
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    /*You just need this if you are only concerned with android and not desktop browsers.*/
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}    
input[type="text"], textarea, [contenteditable]
{

    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle for it ?

Comment: `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.press, img, .press:focus, img:focus{
    outline: 0 !important;
    border:0 none !important;
}
```

Comment: Now try the above I made changes.

Comment: i am still getting the same error Rohan. I am actually using android platform with an augmented reality application which displays a browser on top of camera.

Comment: hi rohan thanks for the support but the error still remains and i get a new black background around the image..

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS:

** HTML **

```
<button class="press">
    <img src="but.png" width="150" height="62" border="0"/>
</button>
```

** CSS **

```
.press{
    outline-width: 0;
}

.press:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer take from here: [How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-do-i-disable-the-highlight-border-on-an-html-input-text-element)

Answer (score 0):

It may be the background color or the border color on the div that includes the button. Else 
use a code like following to remove the css after click completely

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
   $("#displayPanel div").removeClass('someClass');
});
```